# Circuits v3.2 Manager.py **events.effects** Issue

Tags: circuits-framework

Has anyone noticed errors or event.effect errors when using Version 3.2 of Circuits? I've received the message:

```
Apr 15 03:48:05 **** resilient-circuits[11462]: event.effects -= 1
Apr 15 03:48:05 **** resilient-circuits[11462]: *AttributeError: 'ThreatServiceLookupEvent' object has no attribute 'effects'*
```

which seems to be coming from circuits. Specifically  `line 738` of the the `Manager.py script`.

```
[Manager.py]: <https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/59b2a7be553fa788d06e7575b39a5eb2ec96f884/circuits/core/manager.py#L738>
```

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug. Could you file an issue on the issue tracker with a reproducer if you can?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I'm not familiar with filing an issue via issue tracker, but I would be happy to do so if I could ask for the correct place to navigate to.

Comment: I've explored the Github repo and noticed the circuits-framework issues tab there. I will file my issue there!

Comment: **Note - Updated the issue here: https://github.com/circuits/circuitsframework.com/issues/1

Comment: SO is not tech support for this software. Nor is SO for ongoing discussions about such issues here in the comments. You need to create a [mcve] of the problem which can be solved here or delete this altogether.[ask]